# jQuery fadeOut() not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class='toast' onload='function(){setTimeout(function(e){$(this).fadeOut()}, 2000)}'>
<div class='toastIcon'><img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'></div>
<div class='toastLabel'><h1>Weather: Sunny</h1><p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.</div></div>
```

I'm trying to make the div `.toast` fade out when it is clicked. Currently, when it is clicked, nothing happens. I have the latest version of jQuery implemented correctly.

Comment: Take the `onclick=` part and put it inside a `<script>` tag after you've included jquery.

Comment: divs don't have onload attributes. Only the document has, use a `<script>` take like @freedomn-m suggests and use a `$(document).on('load',...` to run your code.

Comment: @user3154108 Maybe not. He want's to remove it when it get's clicked. Check out my answer below.

Comment: @Mr.Jo you are right, I read the code more than the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you. As you asked, we're fading out now on click. I've added `"slow"` to the `fadeOut` function, because I would prefer this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toast' onclick='jQuery(this).fadeOut("slow")'>
    <div class='toastIcon'><img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'></div>
    <div class='toastLabel'><h1>Weather: Sunny</h1>
        <p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.</div>
</div>
```

Another solution by using your timeout:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  $( ".toast" ).click( function () {
   setTimeout( function () {
    $( ".toast" ).fadeOut();
   }, 2000 );
  } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toast">
  <div class="toastIcon">
    <img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'>
  </div>
  <div class="toastLabel">
    <h1>Weather: Sunny</h1>
    <p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way is that you call a function when clicking on the element:

```js
function fadeOutToast() {
  setTimeout( function () {
    $( ".toast" ).fadeOut();
  }, 2000 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toast" onclick="fadeOutToast()">
  <div class="toastIcon">
    <img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'>
  </div>
  <div class="toastLabel">
    <h1>Weather: Sunny</h1>
    <p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can choose what fits best to your project. If I were you, I would do it that way (finally):

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  $( ".toast" ).click( function () {
   $( ".toast" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
  } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toast">
  <div class="toastIcon">
    <img src='weather_sunny-icon.png'>
  </div>
  <div class="toastLabel">
    <h1>Weather: Sunny</h1>
    <p>Today's weather forecast predicts sunshine.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I've been tearing my hair out for ages over this!

Comment: @KiranEvans Thank God I could help before you went bald.

Comment: Thank you! And don't worry, I still have (most of) my hair. Another problem I have is how would I do it so it automatically fades 5 seconds after it's created?

Comment: So it should fade out 5 seconds after it got created? If yes, ask a new question and describe how the element get's created and I'll answer it there. Because the rule here is to ask one question for one topic. Post the link as comment and I'll check it out.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'll put it in a separate question.

Comment: I finally managed to post another question. I didn't know you could only post a question once every 90 mins.